# Android: Get address of an image using ExifInterface in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, exif, android-exifinterface

Is it possible to get the image address using ExifInterface? On Android, while viewing the exif information image has the address populated.

Comment: What do you mean by "image address"?

Comment: @CommonsWare Location at which image was taken, assuming you have location sharing turn on camera app.

Comment: My guess is that you are looking for https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface#TAG_GPS_LATITUDE and https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface#TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE